# How does Spark compute number of partitions?

Tags: apache-spark

My /accounts/* directory has 7 files with size of each file less than block size.

I want to know how Spark computes Partition. 2nd Argument to "textFile" method is hint to Spark for number of Partitions but is there any logic based on which it decides number of Partitions.

For 10 as input, it gives 15 partition, For 20 as input, it gives 25 partitions

How this is being computed?

Regards!

```
scala> var accounts= sc.textFile("/accounts/*",3)

scala> accounts.toDebugString
15/10/12 02:41:45 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to  process : 7
res0: String = 
(7) /accounts/* MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:21 []
 |  /accounts/* HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at <console>:21 []

scala> var accounts= sc.textFile("/accounts/*",10)
scala> accounts.toDebugString
15/10/12 02:42:01 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
res1: String = 
 (15) /accounts/* MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:21 []
 |   /accounts/* HadoopRDD[2] at textFile at <console>:21 []

scala> var accounts= sc.textFile("/accounts/*",20)
scala> accounts.toDebugString
15/10/12 02:42:01 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
res1: String = 
 (23) /accounts/* MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:21 []
 |   /accounts/* HadoopRDD[2] at textFile at <console>:21 []
```

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Good question Daniel, curious about Behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Spark does not compute the number of partitions. It just passes the hint on to the Hadoop library. What does Hadoop do with it? It depends. Look at the documentation (or more likely the code) of the specific `InputFormat`'s `getSplits` method.

For example for `TextInputFormat` the code is in [`FileInputFormat.getSplits`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#L380). It's very complicated and depends on several configuration parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when reading from HDFS spark will create an RDD with a partition per HDFS block.

More details on how the partitions flow through the pipeline and what you can tune [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/).